# Custom Query in Cakephp 3.0?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to make a custom query in Cakephp. I've been reading this: [Query Builder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#)

The problem that every example are like:

```
$query = $articles->find()
->where([
    'author_id' => 3,
    'OR' => [['view_count' => 2], ['view_count' => 3]],
]);
```

But in my PostController I have this:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $post = $this->Posts->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ]);
    $this->set('post', $post);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['post']);
}
```

**I don't have anything with find(). And I don't know what is doing the last part of code**

This is the query that I want to use:

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $posts->find()->where([
    'userfk' => 1
    ]);
}
```

But it isn't working, I don't know how to display the query result.
How can I have the code to working right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use Query Builder

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

**PostsController.php**

```
public function index() {

   $posts = $this -> Posts -> find() -> where(['userfk' => 1]);

   $this -> set('post', $posts);

}
```

By the way, if the result get few **$posts**

Your set should be  `$this -> set('posts', $posts);` and your view have

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
  <!-- your code -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

///////
***EDIT
Adding Paginator option***

**PostsController.php**

```
public function index() {

    $this -> paginate['contain'] = ['Users']; 
    $this -> paginate['conditions'] = ['Posts.userfk' => 1]; 

    $this -> set('posts' , $this -> paginate($this -> Posts)); 
}
```

Comment: @JackeBBudyñski 
Now I have problem with the view (and the view was working fine):Notice (8): Undefined index: pageCount [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 668]. Now, if I put: public function index() { $this->paginate = [ 'contain' => ['Users'] ]; $posts = $this -> Posts -> find() -> where(['userfk' => 1]); $this -> set('posts', $this->paginate()); } the page show me all the row ( the userfk =>1) not workin

Comment: @JackeBBudyñski thanks for helping. Is too dificult put instead of "'Posts.userfk' => 1]" something like: 'Posts.userfk' => $idUser] ?
How can I change the code to this variable?

Comment: $idUser is Auth user? or you want pass this variable via POST ?

Comment: @JackeBBudyñski  No, the user have id (the Auth user), name, and countryId.
On login, I want to save the country id of the user (somewhere and I don't know how) and use the id on the where clause: ['Posts.userfk' => $countryIdUser]

Comment: You can pass variable via post `index($id = nul)` and `['Posts.userfk' => $id]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115522/discussion-between-federick-jons-and-jacek-b-budzynski).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $posts->find()->where([
    'userfk' => 1
    ]);

    //or you can use dynamic finders
    $query = $posts->findByUserfk(1);

    $this->set('post', $query);
}
```

in your view. print all result;

```
pr($post);
```

or you can use foreach to iterate the result

```
foreach($post as $i => $val) {
    echo $val->userfk;
}
```

Comment: You are not answering my question.

Comment: thats the way to display results.... And theres no problem in your query..

Comment: you can try to use dynamic finders... $post->findByUserfk(1);

Comment: and you forget $this->set('post', $query);

Comment: Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File /src/Controller/PostsController.php 
Line: 21. And the line is:
 $query = $posts->find()->where([ ....
I think the problem is in the find()

Comment: in that case the model is not declared in the class
put this it inside the class. 
public $uses = array('Posts', 'OrWhateverModelName');

Comment: Ok may be you can write to me to: a.3710@hotmail.com for a specific question pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115471/discussion-between-federick-jons-and-joshua-belarmino).

Answer (score 0):

Load Model before use in function

Please use in controller

```
public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadModel('Posts');
}
```

Then Index function:-

```
public function index()
{
$posts = $this->Posts->find('all', ['conditions' => ['userfk' => 1]]);

$this->set('posts',$posts);
//pr($posts->toArray());// Print Posts array
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @SonuVerma, but now I have a problem in the view when i put what you said: Notice (8): Undefined variable: posts [APP/Template/Posts/index.ctp, line 24]. And the line 24 is: 
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
            <tr> ....</tr>

Comment: public function index()
{
$posts = $this->Posts->find('all', ['conditions' => ['userfk' => 1]]);

$this->set('posts', $posts);
}

Comment: Check my Index function again

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why do you pass $pots in( $query = $posts->find()).

```
public function index()
{
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', ['conditions' => ['userfk' => 1]]);

 $this->set('post', $posts );

//print_r($posts);you can print array.

}
```

Comment: Now I have problem with the view (and the view was working fine):Notice (8): Undefined index: pageCount [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 668]. Now, if I put:
public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Users']
        ];
        $posts = $this -> Posts -> find() -> where(['userfk' => 1]);
        $this -> set('posts', $this->paginate());
    } the page show me all the row ( the userfk =>1) not working